# How to automatically generate a stack diagram for a PostScript expression?

Tags: pstricks, programming, postscript

The following figure shows a PostScript expression and its stack diagrams step by step. Is there any package to generate it out of the box? If there is no such a package, how to generate it automatically for any PostScript expression? I don't want to write my own interpreter for sure.

[image]

Any methods are welcome.

Comment: Do you need it just for debugging? Or do you want to write a PS manual? For the first task I use `pstack` PS command.

Comment: @AlexG: I want to write a tutorial about PostScript so it must be typeset by (La)TeX.

Comment: I've got a [postscript procedure](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/8NvOEccl_eg/discussion) to print the stack on one line. This might be useful in generating the values for arbitrary code.

Comment: Yes, [it was useful.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160503/21041)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just for fun (or typing exercise or whatever) with TikZ.

It's not complete, but should be trivial to implement the remaining postscript stack commands.

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\makeatletter
\newcount\stacktop
\def\stackclear{\global\stacktop=0\relax}

\def\stackpush#1{%
  \global\advance\stacktop by1\relax
  \expandafter\xdef\csname stack@item@\the\stacktop\endcsname{#1}%
}
\def\stackpeek#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(#1)}%
  \edef#2{\csname stack@item@\pgfmathresult\endcsname}%
}
\def\stackpop#1{%
  \ifnum\stacktop>0\relax
    \edef#1{\csname stack@item@\the\stacktop\endcsname}%
    \global\advance\stacktop by-1\relax
  \fi%
}

\def\stackswap#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{int(#1)}\let\a=\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{int(#2)}\let\b=\pgfmathresult
  \edef\tmp{\csname stack@item@\a\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname stack@item@\a\endcsname{\csname stack@item@\b\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname stack@item@\b\endcsname{\tmp}%
}

\def\stackroll{%
  \stackpop\R%
  \stackpop\r%
  \pgfmathparse{int(\R < 0 ? -\R : \R)}\let\RR=\pgfmathresult 
  \pgfmathloop%
  \ifnum\pgfmathcounter>\RR\relax
  \else%
    \ifnum\R<0\relax%
      \stackrollneg%
    \else%
      \stackrollpos%
    \fi%
  \repeatpgfmathloop%
}

\def\stackrollpos{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfmathloop%
    \ifnum\pgfmathcounter=\r
    \else%
      \stackswap{\stacktop-\pgfmathcounter+1}{\stacktop-\pgfmathcounter}%
    \repeatpgfmathloop%
  \endgroup%
}

\def\stackrollneg{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfmathloop%
    \ifnum\pgfmathcounter=\r
    \else%
      \stackswap{\stacktop-\r+\pgfmathcounter+1}{\stacktop-\r+\pgfmathcounter}%
    \repeatpgfmathloop%
  \endgroup%
}

\def\at{@}

\def\stackmathparse#1{%
  \pgfmathparse{(#1) == int(#1) ? int(#1) : (#1)}%
}
\tikzset{%
  postscript parse/.code={%
    \stackclear%
    \tikzset{ps/parse={#1 @}}%
  },
  ps/.cd,
  parse/.code args={#1 #2}{%
    \def\rest{#2}%
    \def\current{#1}%
    \tikzset{ps/commands/#1={#2}}%
    \tikzset{xshift=1cm}
    \node at (0,.75) {#1};
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\j=int(\stacktop-\i);}] in {0,...,5}
      \node [draw, minimum width=.75cm, minimum height=0.5cm] at (0,-\i/2) {\stackpeek{\j}{\x}\x};
    \ifx\rest\at%
    \else
     \tikzset{ps/parse={#2}}%
    \fi%
  },
  commands/.cd,
    .unknown/.code={\stackpush{\current}},
    exch/.code={\stackswap{\stacktop}{\stacktop-1}},
    roll/.code={\stackroll},
    dup/.code={\stackpeek{\stacktop}{\x}\stackpush{\x}},
    mul/.code={\stackpop{\x}\stackpop{\y}\stackmathparse{\y*\x}\stackpush{\pgfmathresult}},
    add/.code={\stackpop{\x}\stackpop{\y}\stackmathparse{\y+\x}\stackpush{\pgfmathresult}},
    sub/.code={\stackpop{\x}\stackpop{\y}\stackmathparse{\y-\x}\stackpush{\pgfmathresult}},
    div/.code={\stackpop{\x}\stackpop{\y}\stackmathparse{\y/\x}\stackpush{\pgfmathresult}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{postscript parse={4 2 1 exch add 1 sub add}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\[0.25in]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{postscript parse={4 3 2 1 3 1 roll 3 -1 roll}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\[0.25in]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{postscript parse={3 2 dup mul 5 add exch div}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Using bash or a similar command line, executing

```
s="";for i in 4  2  1 add 1 sub add ; do  s="$s $i"; echo " $s pstack" | gs -q -sDEVICE=pbm  | sed -e "s/GS>/\\\\foo{$i}{/" -e "s/GS<[0-9]*>/}/" ; done
```

produces

```
\foo{4}{4
}\foo{2}{2
4
}\foo{1}{1
2
4
}\foo{add}{3
4
}\foo{1}{1
3
4
}\foo{sub}{2
4
}\foo{add}{6
}
```

and then if you wrap that in some latex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo#1#2{%
\parbox[t]{3em}{\centering
\textbf{#1}%
\xfoo#2\$ }}

\def\xfoo#1 {\ifx\$#1\else\\#1 \expandafter\xfoo\fi}

\begin{document}

% s="";for i in 4  2  1 add 1 sub add ; do  s="$s $i"; echo " $s pstack" | gs -q -sDEVICE=pbm  | sed -e "s/GS>/\\\\foo{$i}{/" -e "s/GS<[0-9]*>/}/" ; done


\foo{4}{4
}\foo{2}{2
4
}\foo{1}{1
2
4
}\foo{add}{3
4
}\foo{1}{1
3
4
}\foo{sub}{2
4
}\foo{add}{6
}

\end{document}
```

You get

[image]

Comment: Wow, you're doing post-substitutions on the prompts? And doing the "factorial" of program prefixes?? That's wild. You can also redefine the `/prompt` procedure to produce different output from gs. I've got a *jazzed-up* prompt procedure [here](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/data/prepr.ps).

Answer (score 6):

For **rendering** such a stack, I provide the below solution.  But as Jake points out, it does not digest a *raw* postscript expression.  However, see the end of this answer to see how I can digest David's bash output.

Here, I use a bunch of nested stacks.  The `\psdepth` (depth of stack tube), `\pswidth` (width of stack tube), and `\psrule` (stack rule thickness) may all be tuned.

REEDITED to make the input syntax easier.  There is no limit to the stack depth, as there was in an earlier EDIT.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\def\psdepth{2cm}
\def\pswidth{.5cm}
\def\psrule{.15ex}
\def\psbar{\rule[-\psdepth]{\psrule}{\psdepth}}
\def\pspipe{\psbar\kern\pswidth\psbar}
\def\pscell#1{\stackunder{\footnotesize#1}{\rule{\pswidth}{\psrule}}}
\newcounter{index}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\psstack[2]{%
  \getargsC{#2}%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \def\psstackdata{}%
  \whiledo{\theindex<\narg}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \protected@edef\thisarg{\csname arg\romannumeral\theindex\endcsname}%
    \protected@edef\psstackdata{%
      \psstackdata\protect\pscell{\thisarg}}%
    \ifthenelse{\theindex<\narg}{\protected@edef\psstackdata{%
      \psstackdata \\}}{}%
  }%
  \sffamily\def\stacktype{L}%
  \stackunder{%
    \def\stacktype{S}\stackunder{#1}{\pspipe}%
   }{%
    \def\stacktype{S}\setstackgap{S}{3pt}\expandafter%
      \Shortunderstack\expandafter{\psstackdata}%
   }%
 \hspace{1ex}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\psstack{4}{4}
\psstack{2}{2 4}
\psstack{1}{1 2 4}
\psstack{exch}{2 1 4}
\psstack{add}{3 4}
\psstack{1}{1 3 4}
\psstack{sub}{2 4}
\psstack{add}{6}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Defining `\foo` as

```
\newcommand\foo[2]{%
  \getargsC{#2}%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \def\psstackdata{}%
  \whiledo{\theindex<\numexpr\narg-1}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \protected@edef\thisarg{\csname arg\romannumeral\theindex\endcsname}%
    \protected@edef\psstackdata{%
      \psstackdata\protect\pscell{\thisarg}}%
    \ifthenelse{\theindex<\narg}{\protected@edef\psstackdata{%
      \psstackdata \\}}{}%
  }%
  \sffamily\def\stacktype{L}%
  \stackunder{%
    \def\stacktype{S}\stackunder{#1}{\pspipe}%
   }{%
    \def\stacktype{S}\setstackgap{S}{3pt}\expandafter%
      \Shortunderstack\expandafter{\psstackdata}%
   }%
 \hspace{1.85ex}%
}
```

in my syntax allows one to digest David's bash output and present it with my rendering.

Comment: I think the OP wants to generate the diagram *automatically* from a PS expression.

Comment: @Jake  I see what you mean.  But I don't know enough about "postscript" expressions" to do the conversion.  But perhaps a front end to this code could be adapted to feed it the data.

Answer (score 4):

The automatic generation is easy to realize with LuaTeX, which I leave to the reader ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multido}
\newcount\stackNo  \def\maxStackNo{6}
\makeatletter
\newtoks\ps@stack
\def\addtotoks#1{\ps@stack=\expandafter{\the\ps@stack#1}}

\newcommand*\psstack[2]{%
    \sffamily\stackNo=0
    \ps@stack={\,\tabular[t]{ |c| }
               \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{\Large#1}}}
    \expandafter\psstack@i#2,,\@nil}
\def\psstack@i#1,#2,#3\@nil{\addtotoks{\\\hline}%
    \addtotoks{#1}%
    \global\advance\stackNo by \@ne  
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\def\next{\psstack@ii}%
    \else\def\next{\psstack@i#2,#3\@nil}%
    \fi\next}
\def\psstack@ii{%
  \loop
  \expandafter\ifnum\the\stackNo<\maxStackNo
    \addtotoks{~\\\hline}\advance\stackNo by \@ne
  \repeat
  \addtotoks{\endtabular\,}%
  \the\ps@stack \ps@stack={}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}    
\psstack{4}   {4}
\psstack{2}   {2,4}
\psstack{1}   {1,2,4}
\psstack{exch}{2,1,4}
\psstack{add} {3,4}
\psstack{1}   {1,3,4}
\psstack{sub} {2,4}
\psstack{add} {6}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice solution, Herbert!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg see Jake's comment on the first answer, I believe the question wants the stack to be _determined_ not supplied

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I missed that. Then I guess it isn't that nice after all. `:)`

Comment: Is it possible to use PSTricks to automatically construct the diagram? (because in my opinion, PSTricks has a direct access to PostScript then it should be possible)

Answer (score 4):

As for generating the content for the stack pictures, I've been inspired by this question to clean up some old code and now we can generate nice traces for arbitrary postscript.

The program is posted to [github](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/debug.ps) (and some early drafts in [comp.lang.postscript](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/c6ILVasRXzI/discussion)), as it's a little long to cut+paste. And it is also a step-wise debugger, accepting an executable name, string, array, or file. *The code is mostly level-1 postscript with the exception of `<<` and `>>` and could potentially be down-ported to run on level-1 interpreters, but it is quite wasteful of memory and might not be practical to use in memory-constrained environments without a garbage collector.*

For these code fragments:

```
1 2 3 add add 
6 eq { 8 9 add = } { 9 10 add = } ifelse
```

And:

```
 1 2 3 add add 
  6 eq { 7 } if

 9 { 
     5   
     count 4 gt {
         exit
     } if
 } repeat

  { 55 exit } loop

    (continuation) =

    0 1 10 {
        dup 5 eq {exit} if
    } for
```

I get the following stack trace output:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
 %|- 
1  %|- 1 
2  %|- 1 2 
3  %|- 1 2 3 
add  %|- 1 5 
add  %|- 6 
6  %|- 6 6 
eq  %|- true 
{8 9 add =}  %|- true {8 9 add =} 
{9 10 add =}  %|- true {8 9 add =} {9 10 add =} 
ifelse  %|- 
8  %|- 8 
9  %|- 8 9 
add  %|- 17 
= 17

 %|- 
1  %|- 1 
2  %|- 1 2 
3  %|- 1 2 3 
add  %|- 1 5 
add  %|- 6 
6  %|- 6 6 
eq  %|- true 
{7}  %|- true {7} 
if  %|- 
7  %|- 7 
9  %|- 7 9 
{5 count 4 gt {exit} if}  %|- 7 9 {5 count 4 gt {exit} if} 
repeat  %|- 7 
5  %|- 7 5 
count  %|- 7 5 2 
4  %|- 7 5 2 4 
gt  %|- 7 5 false 
{exit}  %|- 7 5 false {exit} 
if  %|- 7 5 
8  %|- 7 5 8 
{5 count 4 gt {exit} if}  %|- 7 5 8 {5 count 4 gt {exit} if} 
repeat  %|- 7 5 
5  %|- 7 5 5 
count  %|- 7 5 5 3 
4  %|- 7 5 5 3 4 
gt  %|- 7 5 5 false 
{exit}  %|- 7 5 5 false {exit} 
if  %|- 7 5 5 
7  %|- 7 5 5 7 
{5 count 4 gt {exit} if}  %|- 7 5 5 7 {5 count 4 gt {exit} if} 
repeat  %|- 7 5 5 
5  %|- 7 5 5 5 
count  %|- 7 5 5 5 4 
4  %|- 7 5 5 5 4 4 
gt  %|- 7 5 5 5 false 
{exit}  %|- 7 5 5 5 false {exit} 
if  %|- 7 5 5 5 
6  %|- 7 5 5 5 6 
{5 count 4 gt {exit} if}  %|- 7 5 5 5 6 {5 count 4 gt {exit} if} 
repeat  %|- 7 5 5 5 
5  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 
count  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 5 
4  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 5 4 
gt  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 true 
{exit}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 true {exit} 
if  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 
exit  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 
{55 exit}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 {55 exit} 
loop  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 
55  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 
exit  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 
(continuation)  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 (continuation) 
= continuation
 %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 
0  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 
1  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 
10  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 10 
{dup 5 eq {exit} if}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 10 {dup 5 eq {exit} if} 
for  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 
dup  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 0 
5  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 0 5 
eq  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 false 
{exit}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 false {exit} 
if  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 
1  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 
1  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 1 
10  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 1 10 
{dup 5 eq {exit} if}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 1 10 {dup 5 eq {exit} if} 
for  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 
dup  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 1 
5  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 1 5 
eq  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 false 
{exit}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 false {exit} 
if  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 
2  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 
1  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 1 
10  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 1 10 
{dup 5 eq {exit} if}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 1 10 {dup 5 eq {exit} if} 
for  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 
dup  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 2 
5  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 2 5 
eq  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 false 
{exit}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 false {exit} 
if  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 
3  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 
1  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 1 
10  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 1 10 
{dup 5 eq {exit} if}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 1 10 {dup 5 eq {exit} if} 
for  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 
dup  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 3 
5  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 3 5 
eq  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 false 
{exit}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 false {exit} 
if  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 
4  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 
1  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 1 
10  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 1 10 
{dup 5 eq {exit} if}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 1 10 {dup 5 eq {exit} if} 
for  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 
dup  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 4 
5  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 4 5 
eq  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 false 
{exit}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 false {exit} 
if  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 
5  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 5 
1  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 5 1 
10  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 5 1 10 
{dup 5 eq {exit} if}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 5 1 10 {dup 5 eq {exit} if} 
for  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 5 
dup  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 5 5 
5  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 
eq  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 5 true 
{exit}  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 5 true {exit} 
if  %|- 7 5 5 5 5 55 0 1 2 3 4 5 
exit GS<12>
```

Answer (score 2):

I happen to have implemented a limited (and largely untested) postscript interpreter in Asymptote. Out of sheer perversity, I decided to incorporate it into an Asymptote-based answer to this question.

For readability, I've separated the preamble from the body of the document.

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt, convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
%Install the interpreter:
\begin{asydef}
private bool operator cast(string s) {
  if (s == "true") return true;
  else if (s == "false") return false;
  assert(false, 'Attempted to cast the string "' + s + '" to bool. Only the strings "true" and "false" can be cast to bool.');
  return false;
}

private string operator cast(bool b) {
  if (b) return "true";
  else return "false";
}

private real operator cast(string s) { return (real)s; }
private string operator cast(real r) { return (string)r; }
private string operator cast(int i) { return (string)i; }
private int operator cast(string s) { return (int)s; }
private string[] operator cast(real[] rr) {
  return sequence(new string(int j) {return rr[j];}, rr.length);
}
private real[] operator cast(string[] ss) {
  return sequence(new real(int i) {return ss[i];}, ss.length);
}

string[] getnext(string function) {
  int firstSplitPosition = 0;
  while (substr(function, pos=firstSplitPosition, n=1) == ' '
     && firstSplitPosition < length(function)) ++firstSplitPosition;
  int secondSplitPosition = firstSplitPosition;
  while (substr(function, pos=secondSplitPosition, n=1) != ' '
     && secondSplitPosition < length(function)) ++secondSplitPosition;
  string candidateop = substr(function, pos=firstSplitPosition, n=secondSplitPosition - firstSplitPosition);
  if (substr(candidateop, pos=0, n=1) != '{')
    return new string[] {candidateop, substr(function, pos=secondSplitPosition)};

  int braces = 1;
  while (braces > 0) {
    ++secondSplitPosition;
    string s = substr(function, pos=secondSplitPosition, n=1);
    if (s == '}') --braces;
    else if (s == '{') ++braces;
  }
  ++secondSplitPosition;

  return new string[] {substr(function, pos=firstSplitPosition, n=secondSplitPosition - firstSplitPosition), substr(function, pos=secondSplitPosition)};
}

void apply(string function, string[] executionstack);

/* Note: It might be more efficient to create a map data structure
 * from strings to functions. But it might not, and it would certainly
 * be more work.
 */
void executeOp(string op, string[] executionstack) {

  void push(string s) {executionstack.push(s);}
  string pop() { return executionstack.pop(); }

  if (op == "add") push((real)pop() + (real)pop());
  else if (op == "sub") push(-(real)pop() + (real)pop());
  else if (op == "mul") push((real)pop() * (real)pop());
  else if (op == "div") push(1/(real)pop() * (real)pop());
  else if (op == "idiv") { int b = (int)pop(); push(quotient((int)pop(), b)); }
  else if (op == "mod") { int b = (int)pop(); push((int)pop() % b); }
  else if (op == "neg") { push(-(real)pop()); }
  else if (op == "abs") { push(abs((real)pop())); }
  else if (op == "ceiling") { push(ceil((real)pop())); }
  else if (op == "floor") { push(floor((real)pop())); }
  // NOT IMPLEMENTED: round, truncate
  else if (op == "sqrt") { push(sqrt((real)pop())); }
  else if (op == "sin") { push(Sin((real)pop())); }
  else if (op == "cos") { push(Cos((real)pop())); }
  else if (op == "atan") { real b = (real)pop(); real a = (real)pop(); push(degrees(atan2(a,b))); }
  else if (op == "exp") { real b = (real)pop(); real a = (real)pop(); push(a^b); }
  else if (op == "ln") { push(log((real)pop())); }
  else if (op == "log") { push(log10((real)pop())); }
  // NOT IMPLEMENTED: cvi, cvr


  else if (op == "eq") { if (pop() == pop()) push("true"); else push("false"); }
  else if (op == "ne") { if (pop() != pop()) push("true"); else push("false"); }
  else if (op == "gt") {real b = pop(); real a = pop(); push((string)(a > b)); }
  else if (op == "ge") {real b = pop(); real a = pop(); push((string)(a >= b)); }
  else if (op == "lt") {real b = pop(); real a = pop(); push((string)(a < b)); }
  else if (op == "le") {real b = pop(); real a = pop(); push((string)(a <= b)); }
  // NOT IMPLEMENTED: bitwise operations, including bitshift
  else if (op == "and") {push((bool)pop() & (bool)pop()); }
  else if (op == "or")  {push((bool)pop() | (bool)pop()); }
  else if (op == "xor") {push((bool)pop() ^ (bool)pop()); }
  else if (op == "not") {push(!(bool)pop()); }
  else if (op == "true"){push("true"); }
  else if (op == "false"){push("false"); }


  else if (op == "if") {
    string expr = pop();
    bool truefalse = pop();
    if (truefalse) {
      // remove the opening and closing braces
      expr = substr(expr, pos=1, n=length(expr)-2);
      apply(expr, executionstack);
    }
  }
  else if (op == "ifelse") {
    string iffalse = pop();
    string iftrue = pop();
    string expr = (pop() ? iftrue : iffalse);
    expr = substr(expr, pos=1, n=length(expr)-2);
    apply(expr, executionstack);
  }
  else if (op == "pop") pop();
  else if (op == "exch") { string b = pop(); string a = pop(); push(b); push(a); }
  else if (op == "dup") { push(executionstack[executionstack.length - 1]); }
  else if (op == "copy") {
    int n = pop();
    int start = executionstack.length - n;
    executionstack.append(executionstack[start:]);
  }
  else if (op == "index") {
    int n = pop();
    push(executionstack[executionstack.length - n - 1]);
  }
  else if (op == "roll") {
    int j = pop();
    int n = pop();
    int start = executionstack.length - n;
    string[] temp = executionstack[start:];
    temp.cyclic = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      executionstack[start + i] = temp[i-j];
    }
  }

  else push(op);

}

apply = new void(string function, string[] executionstack) {
  string op;
  do {
    string[] next = getnext(function);
    op = next[0];
    function = next[1];
    if (op != '') executeOp(op, executionstack);
  } while (op != '');
};

real[] apply(string function, real[] stack) {
  string[] executionstack = stack;
  apply(function, executionstack);
  return executionstack;
}

real colsep = 12pt;
void drawcolumn(string op, string[] stack, real rowheight = 18pt, real tableheight = stack.length * rowheight) {
    label(op, align=E, position=(0,0));
    real colwidth = 20pt;
    real currentvert = 0;
    for (int i = stack.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        string entry = stack[i];
        currentvert -= rowheight;
        picture pic;
        label(pic, entry);
        real labelwidth = max(pic).x - min(pic).x;
        colwidth = max(colwidth, labelwidth);
        label(entry, align=E, position=(0, currentvert));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= stack.length; ++i) {
        draw ( shift(0, (-i - 1/2)*rowheight) * ((0,0) -- (colwidth + 2pt, 0)) );
    }
    path vertrule =  (0,-rowheight/2) -- (0, -rowheight/2 - tableheight);
    draw(vertrule ^^ shift(colwidth + 2pt, 0)*vertrule);
    currentpicture = shift(-(colwidth + 2pt + colsep), 0) * currentpicture;
}
void drawtable(string[] ops, real tableheight) {
    string[] stack = {};
    for (string op : ops) {
        apply(op, stack);
        drawcolumn(op, stack, tableheight=tableheight);
    }
}
\end{asydef}
```

The body of the document:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
    string[] ops = {"4", "2", "1", "exch", "add", "1", "sub", "add"};
    drawtable(ops, tableheight=100pt);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]