# LaTeX package for typesetting computer science diagrams i.e. linked list

Tags: diagrams

Could you suggest a package designed specifically to typeset different types of diagrams in computer science, such as linked lists, stacks, queues ? What i'm looking for is something similar to the Q-circuit package, whose main purpose is to typeset quantum circuits.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here was a question about typesetting Postscript stack diagrams, if its at all related to your need: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160246/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stack-diagram-for-a-postscript-expression

Comment: Not quiet, i need a lot of CS diagrams - stacks, queues, graphs, linked lists, FSA, Turing machines, etc...

Comment: Could you provide a (hand-draw) example of what you have in mind?

Comment: @Clément Almost all of these are [directed graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph), so this is easily done with the `automata` library in TikZ.  However, OP is looking for a domain-specific language in which to express these ideas.  Personally, I don't believe such a language exists, but I would find it a nice challenge to implement a such a language given example syntax `;)` Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Well, given that OP hasn't been seen in three months, I guess this question should be closed for now. I'll post something here if I ever find the time to implement something like this – it's an interesting proposal.